# Using a value from html with the name="example"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a page with a form, where you can enter a name. 
When you submit the name, the name is stored under the name "bezeichnung". 
Now i want to use the the input "bezeichnung" as a button label. And append it to the body of the page.

This is the form:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="\User\stl.css"/>
</head>

    <body>
        <h1> Neue Station hinzufügen</h1>
        <form id="stationenformular" name="stationenformular" action="indexAktualisierung.html"  method="get">
            <div>
                <label for="bezeichnung">Bezeichung der neuen Station:</label>
                <input type="text" id="bezeichnung" name="bezeichung" />
            </div>
            <br><br>
            <div>
                <label for="ipadresse"> IP Adresse des  Raspberry Pi:</label>
                <input type="text" id="ipadresse" name="ipadresse"/text> 
            </div>
            <div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Abschicken"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</head>
```

and this the function in another html script:

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("bezeichnung");
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");    // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode(x);            // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t);                            // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Comment: there's a typo in your HTML `<input type="text" id="bezeichnung" name="bezeichung" />` should be `<input type="text" id="bezeichnung" name="bezeichnung" />`

Comment: Is your javascript embedded in the same html file like your html form?

Comment: no it is in another html file

Answer (score 1):

For first your `name` is `bezeichung`, not `bezeichnung`.
Also `getElementsByName`  returns an `array-like object`. You need to get the first item from your elements;

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("bezeichnung")[0]; // Get the first 
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");    // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode(x.value);            // Create a text node with x's value
btn.appendChild(t);                            // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

See example. I added text by default.

```js
var x = document.getElementsByName("bezeichnung")[0];
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");    // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode(x.value);            // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t);                            // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

```html
<body>
    <h1> Neue Station hinzufügen</h1>
    <form id="stationenformular" name="stationenformular" action="indexAktualisierung.html"  method="get">
       <div>
           <label for="bezeichnung">Bezeichung der neuen Station:</label>
           <input type="text" id="bezeichnung" name="bezeichnung" value="Test"/>
       </div>
       <br><br>
       <div>
           <label for="ipadresse"> IP Adresse des  Raspberry Pi:</label>
           <input type="text" id="ipadresse" name="ipadresse"/text> 
       </div>
       <div>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" value="Abschicken"/>
       </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: i.e. `var x = document.getElementsByName("bezeichnung")[0];`

Answer (score 0):

To get a unique instance of the bezeichnung input field, you could use `var x = document.getElementsByName("bezeichnung")[0];` or `var x = document.getElementById("bezeichnung");`

As Suren Srapyan said, `getElementsByName` returns an array of all elements with that name, so you need to specify which one you mean by putting the position in the array of the object you want.

However, as you presumably only want one instance of *bezeichnung*, it's easier to use `getElementById`.

Comment: my problem is, that if i am using getElementById the text in the button is now "null", but it should be "abc" if am entering in the form "abc"
do I have to observe something if I am working with two different html files?

Comment: if the JavaScript is pointing at two different HTML files, either the button needs to have the same ID in both, or you will need to write a separate script for the other button (recommended if the other button does something different)

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("bezeichnung");
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");    // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode(x);            // Create a text node                         
btn.parentNode.insertBefore(t, btn);        // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change getElementsByName with getElementById

```
var x = document.getElementById("bezeichnung");
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");    // Create a <button> element
btn.innerText = x.value;                            // Append the text to <button>
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/radonirinamaminiaina/h0m4xycr/)